# Getting venues from foursquare by tags

Tags: api, foursquare

We are planning to use foursquare api to collect venues data in a particular city in order to build a database of places suitable for parents with kids to spend time together. I need data of all the venues that are family/kids friendly or are specifically for families with kids.

Foursquare app has e.g. tags that indicate whether a particular place is families-friendly. however, I couldn't find in the docs, how to use the API to get places with relevant tags

Please, share links / tutorials from which I could figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

venues have categories and can be listed based on this endpoint. https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories

Below is a good tutorial on getting started with the venues endpoint.
https://blueprintinteractive.com/blog/html5-geolocation-venue-search-powered-foursquare-and-retina-maps